Export Wordpress theme with modifications for other site
I purchased wordpress theme.
No i have upoloaded it on new site and modified it as i wanted.
Now i want to use that theme in my all sites.
Problme is theme also saves its oevrride stuff or modification inside wp options database so even if i zip the theme folder my chnages are not visible in the new site.
Is there any way to export all theme realted stuff and then import it ?

It depends on the theme, you will need to ask its author whether they provide a mechanism for this.

try using the updraft backup plugin to take a backup of your modified theme and restore it to another website.
